# how to save video and audio using video js and fine uploader

Tags: javascript, html, video, video.js, fine-uploader

I am trying to upload video (audio+video) using following code. Locally I am able to record and view the video but it is not uploaded to server. following is my code.

```
// initialize Fine Uploader
var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    debug: true,
    autoUpload:true,
    request: {
        endpoint: 'https://192.168.0.104/rrtc/save.php'
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['webm']
    }
});
// setup videojs-record
var player = videojs('myAudio',
    {
        controls: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        plugins: {
            wavesurfer: {
                src: 'live',
                waveColor: 'black',
                progressColor: '#2E732D',
                cursorWidth: 1,
                msDisplayMax: 20,
                hideScrollbar: true
            },
            record: {
                audio: true,
                video: true,
                maxLength: 5,
                debug: true
            }
        }
    });

// player error handling
player.on('deviceError', function()
{
    console.warn('device error:', player.deviceErrorCode);
});
player.on('error', function(error)
{
    console.log('error:', error);
});

// data is available
player.on('finishRecord', function()
{
    // the blob object contains the audio data
    var audioFile = player.recordedData;

    console.log('finished recording: ', audioFile);

    // upload data to server
    var filesList = [audioFile];
    console.log("F Lengh :"+filesList.length);
    uploader.addFiles(filesList);
});
```

If I change any 1 option from record plugin (Audio and video) to false then I am able to upload the files to server. But if I try with both true options i.e. video:true,audio:true then its not uploaded. 
screen shot of console is added to post. What would be the problem?

[Chrome console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWJYB.jpg)

---

Edit 1:

-Please refer [this link](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/blob/master/examples/upload/fine-uploader.html) as original source from where I am using.

-Video tag `<video id="myAudio" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"></video>`

Answer (score 0):

According to your console output, you are passing an array to `addFiles` containing a single object that itself contains a `video` property, which is a `Blob`. A couple things:

1. If you're only adding one file to `addFiles`, you don't need to pass an array.
2. According to your console output, you aren't passing a `Blob`. Instead, you are passing an object that contains a `Blob` as one of its properties. So, you should pass `audioFile.audio` (I assume) or `videoFile.video` to `addFiles`.

Comment: I tried as you said, butt audioFile var don't have property of audio.

Comment: It worked with audioFile.video. I was able to upload the video without audio

Comment: The [video.js docs](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record#get-recorded-data) suggest the there should be an `audio` property. So there is some issue either with your code, or a bug in your version of video.js, or an error in the video.js docs.